# Comment by new user

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, privileges, convert-to-comment

How come [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4203122/muthu) with no reputation could have commented [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16440468/850848)?

It's not his post nor his question and he should not have [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He posted an answer, and a mod converted it to a comment.

Comment: Personally I don't really see a lot of value in a comment like that and would have just deleted the post, but meh.

Comment: I agree, so I deleted the comment. We often process these pretty quickly, so if we see something more substantial than "thanks, that helped me" we'll convert it to preserve any potentially useful information. There's really none there, so nothing of value is lost.

Comment: I thought it added a bit of color to the answer (demonstrating a successful case), so I converted that to a comment. I was feeling generous towards the new user.

Answer (score -4):

Choices of new user:

1. do nothing

   I do not think holding back new user to contribute is a good idea.
2. post a answer and let a mod convert it to a comment

   The workloads of a mod is already heavy.
3. suggest an edit

   Comments and edit suggestions are two different things.

I think none of the three choices is good.

I suggest just let the new user post the comment,
and notify new user that their comment will be hidden until they have enough points.