# Comment on answer

Tags: discussion, support

StackOverflow blocks new user or user with rep below 50 to leave a comment. I faced this problem too when I wan't to participate to answer the question but I need to ask by leave a comment.

The system not allow me to leave a comment yet on that time so the one and only way that I know to let them know that I am asking is by post an answer but is to ask.

I am pretty sure that many new user has faced this problem too. Some other user who recognize the situation can help by move the answer as the comment but the others always blame user who post as I did before.

If that allowed to post answer as a comment then how to do that and if that't is not allowed then how to give the chance to user want to participate but cannot leave a comment?

**EDITED :**

The system have a good filter to allow 50 rep and above leave a comment to eliminate spam but it's limit the user specially new user with rep below 50 to participate in answer the question.

If new user need to edit the question, if that's edit can make sure the the post will be edited by provide the point of editing, it's is will be help but how to anticipate the user who posted the question will decline the suggestion?

When the new user try to post the answer with not enough information, that's will get downvote by the other, it's not fair to be blamed for the others fault

Comment: Gain some reputation by either answering a question that doesn't need clatification, ask a good question or suggest 25 edits to get to the bar.

Comment: See also this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: And see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164042/158100

Comment: It doesn't help by asking a good question either. It seems like it is totally not allowed to ask any question, as an "Answer Reply" (or, Reply Answer). I understand the problem (spam, quality protection), but it makes it very hard for beginners to work their way up. Asking a question is less initimidating than stating "I know the answer !". Maybe it's considered to be as some sort of test : only the real passionate, will try to find a way through this initiation period. The hypocrite thing is that other people will tell to do by editing posts. Not really the goal, but that works.

Comment: The good question is relative, the good for someone is not sure good someone else.

Comment: @tvCa I don't follow. To ask a question you hit the "ask question" button. You don't post it as an answer to someone elses. Why is this a problem?

Comment: No no, ask a question as reply in an existing thread. I'm talking about actions inside a given thread.

Comment: @Hilarius ... yes, obviously. The thing is : the level is high around here. And, that is a good thing.

Comment: Because of their ephemeral nature, a comment is the action with the least risk of permanent harm to the site. I would have expected them to be one of the things permitted immediately for new users, before writing answers.

Comment: `" I faced this problem too..."` -- we **all** faced this problem when starting out, so why are new new users any different from the rest of us when we were new users? The current system weeds out the casual user from making comments and instead allows the more committed user the privilege which is a good thing. It won't take someone long to build up adequate rep to comment, and if this motivates someone to do so, then that's another good thing.

Comment: Related question: [Comment by new user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275834/comment-by-new-user)

Answer (score -5):

I totally agree with you.

I think that limitation is forcing users to write answer when there is no real need for it and comment is enough.

Comment: It does not force them to write an answer, but it does present them with a choice between not contributing and writing an answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think many people are thinking like you. But I am sure that also many people think that in that case they should write answer.

Comment: @vasili111: So, to paraphrase: Because they haven't yet built the miniscule amount of trust to be allowed to comment, they should show they don't deserve any trust by actively harming the site?

Comment: @Deduplicator They can think that they are helping, not harming.

Comment: @vasili111: I never said they were malicious. Doesn't change anything though.

Comment: It just makes no sense to me that we can't trust people to make a *comment* while we go on and on about how unimportant comments are, yet we expect people to know how to write good answers to questions they can't ask for clarification on, and some of us even suggest that the new users should gain the rep via edits. Because it makes so much sense to stop people from commenting to prevent extra moderation, but tell people to *suggest edits* which *always* adds to the moderation. Wut.