# Having valuable information to an answer but being unable to comment. What to do?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, reputation, wrong-answers

Yesterday I was facing a dilemma I want to know how to handle in the future.

I was researching if it is possible to detect whether the wifi setting on an iOS device is turned on or off. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25956280/2919327) (relatively new and had attracted some upvotes) which claimed that the code provided returns YES/NO depending on the state of the wifi setting.

I tested the code on two different iPhone models. On one of them, the code worked. On the other, the code always returned NO, which is wrong.

Realizing this observation - which is of great importance to anyone using the code in mentioned answer - should be shared in a comment is a no-brainer.

**Problem**: I didn't have enough reputation to comment, which is why I decided to post my observation as an answer (in which I stated that I wish I could've posted it as a comment). Some hours later, I was asked to delete my answer due to it not being an answer, and so I did.

What do you recommend me to do in a situation like this?

Perhaps the obvious answer is not to post, as it is not an answer. I just feel sorry for the people who are in for a major headache.

Comment: Get one more upvote on an answer.  Two if you're paranoid.  Tough spot to be in, I know; but you're *really close*.

Comment: Probably a dup of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278660/comment-on-answer. I think Scott said about this "Don't focus on what you cannot do, focus on what you can."

Comment: "That didn't work on model X" isn't that valuable.  Coming up with an alternative for that model, then posting it as an answer, is.

Comment: This whole idea of the small amount of points just to comment is plain old silly.  Anyone and everyone should be able to comment.  Answers like well you need 10 more points is just mind numbing.

Comment: You should have asked the other guy to comment on bllkjakk's answer .... If it was me I would have done it instinctively :(

Comment: @JonH http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: @chancea - Doesn't help - I -1 on it.

Comment: One approach that seems to have worked for you is to post an intelligent question here on meta and get a few established users to go vote for some of your fine work in SO, thus giving you the rep you need (and deserve imho) to add comments ;)

Comment: I would say it was wrong of Patrick to act like he owns the place and order you to remove the content. For one he could have raised it for someone more diplomatic to handle. But I totally get where you are coming from and your answer did actually provide some info, you cannot begin to imagine the amount of times I have used a piece of code that is assured as working on all devices etc only to find it was never tested

Comment: A few months when I still had less than 50 rep, I was able to post comments by first making a short answer, then before it was posted, I had an automatic message telling me something like "Are you sure you don't want to post it as a comment instead ?". Back then, I though it was a feature and did it a few times. (I even got the [commentator](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator?userid=3702797) badge before [I had the 50 rep needed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=5)). Has this bug/feature been removed since then ?

Comment: And...you now have enough rep to comment. Apparently the solution to your problem is to have a question that is worthy of upvotes, and then asking a question like this on meta. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, mere "commentary" on another post should be a comment and not an answer. You understand that so we're off to a great start.

If you can flesh out your response to be less of a "by the way this doesn't work" and more "here is the full thing I did, I can provide a complete solution and *also* prove that the other answer does not work", that's the most ideal path.

Most of the reason we say "don't put answers in the comments" is because we lose out on making answers *actually* go to the answers section. So often I see quick "one-liner" answers as the first comment on a question, but that user doesn't take the time to make a quality post.

However, if you can't provide that "full explanation", then really you have to rely on comments. You *might* be able to make a suggested edit if you don't alter too much (but be warned that reviewers don't like it when you add possibly other meanings or side information).

Your other option is to work and get the 50 rep requirement for commenting. If the post has a few upvotes, there is a good chance it will still be there when you reach your goal.