# New user: not allowed to comment - what to do when an answer is not correct?

Tags: discussion

I am new on this forum (i.e., I have used it a lot but never before registered). I am looking for an answer and I have found the question that I want to ask too. It only has one answer, this answer is not correct. I do not want to answer this question, but I want to make readers aware that the answer is not correct, hence, the problem is not solved. How can I do this when I do not have rights to comment?

Comment: Thanks :) However, I cannot since you have to have a reputation of at least 5 here to ask a question there :/

Comment: Ok so take this :)

Comment: Its not a forum...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rap-2-h I got to the meta.stackoverflow.com forum, where there are actually some similar questions with answers. 
For example:
[Having valuable information to an answer but being unable to comment. What to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294412/having-valuable-information-to-an-answer-but-being-unable-to-comment-what-to-do)
and:
[Comment on answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278660/comment-on-answer) .

The answers basically say do nothing until you figure out the correct answer or get high enough reputation to comment...

Comment: Yes, it's designed so that totally new users can only participate in limited ways. The idea is that this increases the quality of the content. If someone doesn't know complete answers to any of the questions on the site, and can't ask questions that will attract upvotes either, then the system is designed so that they won't be able to comment, even if they have useful information. That's just part of the tradeoff.